# UWP GridView resize one column on changing size

Tags: windows, gridview, uwp

I have the following page setup, containing a grid view with two columns: image and title. Not all of the rows have images and I am trying to make the image half the row width. So for the rows that no image is available the text should fill the entire row, while the rows with images to display the image on 
half of the row, the title on the rest of the row.

I have used the MathConverter to adjust the imageWidth to half of the actualWidth of row, but on resize (on Desktop when resizing the main window, on Phone/Tablet when changing the device orientation) the image size is not updated.

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <local:MathConverter x:Key="MathConverter"/>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="Compact">
        <ItemsStackPanel/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LargeWidthDataTemplate">
        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ImageURL}" MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=gridView, Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}}" Margin="4"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" 
                               Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <GridView x:Name="gridView" Grid.Row="2" SizeChanged="gridView_SizeChanged"
              ItemsPanel="{StaticResource Compact}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LargeWidthDataTemplate}">
        <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

> For purposes of ElementName binding, ActualWidth does not post updates when it changes (due to its asynchronous and run-time calculated nature). Do not attempt to use ActualWidth as a binding source for an ElementName binding. If you have a scenario that requires updates based on ActualWidth, use a SizeChanged handler.

For more info, see Remarks of the [FrameworkElement.ActualWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx).

So you should be able to add a property in your page and the page need to implements the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface. In the SizeChanged event, we should be able to set the ActualWidth to the property. Then we can bind the `MaxWidth` property to the property.

For example:

```cs
private double myActualWidth;

public double MyActualWidth
{
    get
    {
        return myActualWidth;
    }
    set
    {
        if (myActualWidth != value)
        {
            myActualWidth = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyActualWidth"));
            }
        }
    }
}

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void gridView_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.MyActualWidth = gridView.ActualWidth;
}
```